# Tool to visualize the layout of a WebPage?

Tags: html, website, layout

Before I build it myself, is there a tool that gives me a quick tree-like structure of a webpage? Basically all Divs and other layout element with an overview of their ID and CLASS tags, but no scripts, spans or other non-layout content (and yes, i know that css position:absolute can turn everything into a layout element, but let's ignore that...).

This is to get an overview of Nesting, Inherited CSS classes etc.

*Edit:* I want to print out or copy the outline to annotate it, so it needs to actually strip out any content/non-layout elements.

Answer (score 2):

A great tool for this is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). You can also use the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) toolbar to achieve a "highlight and border" effect on positioned elements.

[image: Firebug]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I want to print out or copy the outline, so that I can annotate it. Firebug doesn't seem to be able to do that :(

Comment: Use Web Developer and highlight divs and positioned elements then.